# Where are all the small functions supposed to go in XP?

Tags: code-organization, extreme-programming

I like the concept of Extreme Programming (as I understand it), that there should be many smaller functions with descriptive names, instead of fewer, longer ones, even if those functions are only called from one piece of code.

I do this all the time, but it does tend to litter the class definition quite a lot. I already mark those "only internal" functions by prepending a "_" to them, but they still take up a lot of editor real estate.

Is there a canonical way to deal with this? For example, write them all in alphabetical order under all the "public" functions, or write them under the function they are called in.

In case it matters I mostly write Python code.

Comment: Run time support and compiler functions typically begin with an underscore, so its preferable to avoid leading underscores when naming functions.

Comment: @user230118 a leading underscore is a [Python convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) to signal that a method is non-public.

Answer (score 2):

XP is a fairly loose collection of best practices and ideas, with the underlying idea to take them to the “extreme”, i.e. to take them seriously and practice them fully.

Keeping functions small is often considered a best practice, but not usually associated with Extreme Programming which is more concerned about process-level best practices. Traditionally, XP was also associated with the Smalltalk language where the issue of organizing methods in a “file” does not arise.

If small functions are a best practice, how might we take it to the extreme without incurring drawbacks such as unorganized files? One potential approach would be to also keep those files smallish. If one module has so much behaviour that it's getting unruly, some of the behaviour could be factored out into another module that is then imported.

I would caution against trying to impose an organization like keeping helper functions in alphabetical order. That gets difficult to maintain, and might not always work in the Python execution model (e.g. on older Python versions, classes must be declared before they can be used as type annotations).

Another potential solution is to reject the idea that small functions are necessarily good. Code should be clear. Often – but not always – code becomes clearer by extracting meaningful parts of behaviour and giving it a name. This becomes especially relevant if those parts can be meaningfully tested in separation. But that would also imply that those behaviours become part of the public interface of the module. This harmonizes well with the previously mentioned idea of small modules: some modules are for “external” use, others for use by tests and by other parts of the codebase.

A note on naming: Python has no true public/private visibility modifiers. However, members starting with an underscore are excluded from the default import list when using `from some_module import *`. Alternatively, you can explicitly provide this list via the `__all__` variable. But this doesn't actually hide the functions – they can be accessed as `some_module._private_var`. In classes, a double underscore causes basic name-mangling, but doesn't make the name truly private either. In general, it seems that the best approach is to keep implementation details in separate module, and then assemble a public interface in an `__init__.py` file via `from .details import public_member` statements.

Comment: I mostly write methods, so your proposal of putting these smaller functions into a separate module sounds like I would need to make the larger method into an Object itself, or a Mixin with the specific behaviour/code that I want to extract.

Comment: @Minix In my experience, it is rare that helpers should be methods. Instead, it's often better to keep them as free functions and pass any required data as parameters. Python is a multi-paradigm language, not everything has to be stuffed into a class. If you're struggling with very large classes, this could indicate that you're straining against the Single Responsibility Principle and that the class should be redesigned anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an organizing principle. Unfortunately there isn't a one size fits all answer here. However, there are options to consider.

You mentioned one: Alphabetize. This helps when code is on paper but any decent editor has a find. Alphabetizing is used when you're giving up on any structural organization of the methods. That, in and of itself, is a warning sign that it might be time to consider a refactoring that will move some of these functions elsewhere so you'll be free to continue decomposing into small functions.

I'll contrast that with Uncle Bob's step down rule that argues for putting the highest level function at the top and gives you more detailed ones as you go down the page. Here organization is strictly structural. But it doesn't tolerate unlimited decomposition in the file isn't focused. It only works if the one file is telling one clear story.

Now sometimes your language is single pass, or you just hate forward declarations, and it makes more sense to flip step down upside down and put main at the bottom. Still you can organize around levels of abstraction. But only if the file is telling one clear story.

There are other organizing principles as well but my chief complaint about making alphabetizing your organizing principle is that it lets you completely ignore the need to tell one clear story in the file. It makes it feel like a page ripped out of a dictionary. Organized, but it lacks a plot.